# Ошибка при записи в базу строки с апострофом

Tags: php, sql

При записи в базу значения `'комп\'ютер'` (с апострофом, так как язык украинский), происходит ошибка.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: код как записываете в студию.

Comment: При записи в базу ипользуйте не подстановку переменных в текст, а привязываемые переменные и тогда никаких проблем никогда не будет. http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php аналогичные функции есть и в PDO

Comment: Для SQL Server будет работать так:  'комп''ютер'

Comment: Базе данных совершенно всё равно, какие символы хранить. А вот если стряпать SQL-команды вручную, то [проблем не избежать](https://xkcd.com/327/). Виновата не база данных.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте экранировать символы перед записью в БД.

Например код апострофа выглядит так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вообще, по этому поводу есть замечательная статья «[Экранирование (или что нужно знать для работы с текстом в тексте)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/182424/)»<sup>[[архив](https://web.archive.org/web/20151027040412/http://habrahabr.ru/post/182424/)]</sup>.

Answer (score -1):

Для устранения ошибки необходимо заменить символ «'» (апостроф) на «`» (гравис).

Ошибка возникла из-за того, что апостроф является служебным символом, определяющим границы строкового значения.

Comment: Но ведь тогда это будет уже другой символ.